# Accessor method for a static final double

Tags: java, methods, return, accessor

I have this variable:
public static final double PRICE_COST = 100.00;

in my accessor method for this, would it look like this?

```
    /**
     * @return the price cost as double
     */
      public double getPRICE_COST(){        
           return PRICE_COST;
      }
```

I'm just not sure the way capitalization should work since it's a final, and if it should be public (final double) as the method header since it's returning a final. Or do I just leave it as a double?
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't bother making an accessor to a public static final, just use the name itself.

Comment: I have to as it's part of my assignment

Comment: Why would you name a variable PRICE_COST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, constants (variables declared as `static final`) don't need accessors. If you do want to use one in this case, it would look like this:

```
public static double getPriceCost() {
    return PRICE_COST;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The person before me is correct. Let me explain a bit of the reason. Variables are declared private or protected (as opposed to none or public) in order to protect them from being changed throughout the course of programming.

Constants, by definition, can't be changed and therefore setting them to public would be fine and cause no damage. To be clear you can use an accessor (or getter), but there is no real reason to. Just set it to public. After it is set initially there would be no reason to fear it would change (if something attempts to you'll get an error).